# PHP parent:: equivalent for objects

Tags: php, oop

```
class Second
{
  // i've got to access to $variable from First instance from here
}

class First
{
  public $variable;
  public $SecondInstance;

  public function __construct($variable) 
  {
    $this->variable = $variable;
    $this->SecondInstance = new Second();
  }
}
 $FirstObj = new First('example variable');
```

I need an equivalent for parent::$variable for objects.

Is there a possibility to do that in that way?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. The only way you can manage that, without extending First, is to pass "$this" to the constructor of Second:

```
$this->SecondInstance = new Second ($this);
```

Or, you can simply pass $variable to its constructor.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to me that I've got to rewrite classes or do that just like you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like the [parent](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php) function in PHP:

```
//You may find yourself writing code that refers to variables 
//and functions in base classes. This is particularly true if 
// your derived class is a refinement or specialisation of 
//code in your base class.

//Instead of using the literal name of the base class in your 
//code, you should be using the special name parent, which refers 
//to the name of your base class as given in the extends declaration 
//of your class. By doing this, you avoid using the name of your base 
//class in more than one place. Should your inheritance tree change 
//during implementation, the change is easily made by simply 
//changing the extends declaration of your class. 


<?php
class A {
    function example() {
    echo "I am A::example() and provide basic functionality.<br />\n";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function example() {
    echo "I am B::example() and provide additional functionality.<br />\n";
    parent::example();
    }
}

$b = new B;

// This will call B::example(), which will in turn call A::example().
$b->example();
?>
```

Comment: There is no 'extend' in the sample code. This is referring to the variables in the 'First' class that substantiated the 'Second' class, so it should be environment variables not parent variables.

Comment: @Waygood Indeed. But this will be a good way to show the OP how to use the extend function to be able to access the variables and functions that they want.

Comment: No, static classes does not satisfy me, but thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you change your strucutre a little to "extend":

```
class second extends first{
    public __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        echo $this->variable;
    }
}
```

Otherwise you will need to assign the "first" as a parent class within the variables on the second and actually access it like that:

```
class second{
    public $first;
    public function __construct($first){
        $this->first = $first;
        var_dump($this->first->variable);
    }
}
```

Or of course you can also make the first class static and access it that way.